# PHPStorm html + .sass подсказки и ссылки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, phpstorm, webstorm

[В блоге компании JetBrains](https://habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/333630/) отражено, что теперь IDE поддерживает `Автодополнение имен классов в HTML-файлах теперь работает для Sass- и SCSS-селекторов, созданных через &`. Это описано относительно WebStorm, но я думаю и PHPStorm не отстает в этом плане.

Вопрос: как подружить `index.html` и `styles.sass` в рамках одного проекта и при возможности исключить из "отношений" скомпилированный CSS файл?
На данный момент HTML файл прекрасно дружит со скомпилированным CSS файлом, но это очень не удобно.  Требуется, чтобы работали подсказки классов как в SASS, так и в HTML, а также работали ссылки при `Ctrl + click`.

Comment: боюсь, что автодополнение не будет работать, если к Вашему `index.html` прилинкован (с помощью `<link>` тега) скомпилированный `.css` файл:( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8090

Comment: удалял скомпилированный файл из проекта, удалял <link> - не помогло